# Finding the same elements with the same index for two vectors

Tags: r, loops, vector, count

I am looking for an efficient way to find the same elements with the same index in two vectors and count them. 
Say I have two vectors and I want to know how many times I had the realization [1,1]
So if I have two vectors (in practice they will be very large), for instance

```
x=c(2,1,8,1,4)
y=c(9,1,8,0,4)
```

I want to count that 1 appeared only once in the same position of x and y.
I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: It feels like I'm missing something, but isn't this just `sum(x == y & x == 1)`?

Comment: I've checked and it didn't count all the same entries which give (1,1)  when comparing the vectors. The reduce approach of akrun works perfectly

Comment: @Arbiturka That's interesting ... they seem logically equivalent, but maybe floating point math is interfering. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, I took simple example to test if it works:  x=c(1,4,1,1,7,1)
 y=c(1,5,1,6,7,1)
 sum(x=y & x==0)
[1] 0
So, I got 0, whereas it should be 3

Comment: @Arbiturka You copied the code wrong, I think. It should be `x==y`, not `x=y`? Also, should be testing `x==1`, but you wrote `x==0`. `sum(x==y & x == 1)` gives 3 for me. Btw, for code in comments, you can use backticks, and for multiline code, break with `;` so it can be copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a `matrix` by `cbind`ing the vectors, check whether it is equal to 1, get the `rowSums`, if both the vectors have 1 at the same position, it will be 2 and if there are only one 1, the value will be 1.  So, convert it to a logical `vector` (`==2` or `==1`) and get the count with `sum`

```
sum(rowSums(cbind(x, y)==1)==2)
sum(rowSums(cbind(x, y)==1)==1)
```

Note that this also checks whether the 1 is in either 'x' or 'y' and not only in 'x'

---

Or with `Reduce`

```
sum(Reduce(`&`, lapply(list(x, y), `==`, 1)))
```

Note that these solutions can be extended to multiple `vector`s instead of just two

Answer (score 0):

For all of those looking for that quick `tidyverse` fix that you so desperately need:

```
library(purrr)

map(list(x, y), ~.== 1) %>% reduce(., `&`) %>% sum
```

For the indices:

```
map(list(x, y), ~.== 1) %>% reduce(., `&`) %>% which
```